# Passing parameters to JAVA main via ANT Build

Tags: java, ant, target

I am totally new to ant and I want to send the arguments 4   4  and 50 to my JAVA main class.  This is what I have so far.

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">

        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
            <arg value ="4"/>
            <arg value ="4"/>
            <arg value ="40"/>
        </java> 
 </target>
```

The error i get is:

```
BUILD FAILED`C:\Users\Admiral Sudoku\Documents\Eduboard\Ken Ton\build.xml:40: The element typ
e "target" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</target>".
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing quote at:

```
<arg value ="40"/>
               ^---- here
```

Also you closed `<java` tag twice:

```
<java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
                                                          ^--- non need for /
```

And your snipped should be inside `<project>` tag.

Also you can "debug" your xml syntax easier if you open `build.xml` in browser. (for example in Firefox).

Comment: Can you edit you question and update with new build.xml and error message please?

Comment: oh, how do you do that

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use this.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="TestApp" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="jar"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="AppRunner"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">

    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="12"/>
        <arg value="15"/>
        <arg value="17"/>
        <arg value="18"/>
        <arg value="20"/>
    </java>

</target>

<target name="main" depends="run"/>

</project>
```